# Remove formatting tags from text inside table cell using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following table with some data inside it.

**HTML**

```
<table id="rcvd">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="scrollable"><b>2016-08-05 17:18:29</b></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to remove the  formatting tags leaving the text intact when I click the row in which this cell is contained. How can I do this with **JQuery** for ONLY that specific table cell ? I don't want to affect the other table cell.

**JS**

```
$('#recvd tr').on("click", function(){
            var td = $(this).find("td");
            $.post("<url>", {data: <something>},
                            function(response)
                            {
                                if (response != 0)
                                {
                                   .....
                                }
                            });
        });
```

Comment: where is `#recvd` ? please add all relevant code to OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `regex` to strip out the HTML tags from a string.

Check the below **snippet**, I think this is what you want.

Hope it **helps**.

```js
$(function(){
$("#rcvd tr").on("click", function(){
     var data = $(this).find("td").html();
     data = data.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
     $(this).find("td").html(data);
     // your code goes here
     console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rcvd">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="scrollable"><b>2016-08-05 17:18:29</b></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATED**

If you want to keep the `div` with `id=scrollable` inside **td**, Then this will be your way to do.

```js
$(function(){
$("#rcvd tr").on("click", function(){
     var data = $(this).find("td > div").html();
     data = data.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
     $(this).find("td > div").html(data);
     // your code goes here
     console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rcvd">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="scrollable"><b>2016-08-05 17:18:29</b></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think console is a good way to go. It doesn't usually show formatted text. Moreover `.text()` does not return the html tags. It will just return the text without the formatting which is what you are printing out in the console.

Comment: @asehgal i replace `.text()` with `.html()` its working.. don't you want that ? or you want something else, thats what i understand your question so far, that you want to strip out the html tags from  within the `td`